# Персонализируемый матрас

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов, реклама

Из рекламы матраса [**iMemory S Plus**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPVKOq6h8VI):
Новый матрас *iMemory S Plus* можно настраивать согласно вашим личным требованиям к комфорту. Отрегулируйте его под контуры вашего тела, ваши потребности и предпочтения в отношении сна простым поворотом матраса. От самых мягких условий до самых жестких.

**Индивидуально персонализируемый комфорт и поддержка;

100% персонализируемый матрас.**

Что-то меня смущает в использовании слова *персонализируемый* в этих словосочетаниях, но вот что именно — никак не могу понять.
А как вы считаете: правильно ли так говорить?

Answer (score 1):

"Индивидуально персонализируемый" - тавтология, если смириться со словом "персонализируемый" вместо "настраиваемый" или "регулируемый".

**P.S.** Вместо странного слогана (если это он выделен жирным):

"Аймемори эс-плас":

Такой матрас,
Что всякий раз
Подстроится под Вас!

Answer (score 1):

Контуры вашего тела... Только силуэт имеет контур.

Предпочтения в отношении сна... Разве не об предпочтении к поверхности речь?

100% персонализируемый матрас... Слово *эргономичный* рекламщик забыл.

Простым поворотом матраса... Имеется опция *Смена стороны горизонта*? Надо брать.

От самых мягких условий до самых жестких... Без комментариев.