# Значение слова ПЕРСОНАЛИЗАЦИЯ

Tags: значение-слов

Слово *персонализация* встречается в интернете в смысле подстраивания чего-либо под персональные особенности конкретной личности. Но в доступных мне словарях такого значения у этого слова нет. Словари говорят о противоположном, то есть о персонализации как изменении самой личности, воплощении, олицетворении чего-либо в конкретной личности.

Ответы на вопрос о "персонализируемом" матрасе ([Персонализируемый матрас](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441137/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81/441138#441138)) не внесли ясность.

Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По всей видимости, составители словарей пребывают в раздумье из-за конфликта смыслов чисто русского термина "персонализация" (введён В. Петровским) из области психологии, обозначающего (если упростить строгие определения) *процесс становления личности*, и английского слова personalization, обозначающего *процесс приведения чего-либо в соответствие с потребностями конкретного человека* (the process of making something suitable for the needs of a particular person - Cambridge Business Dictionary). При локализации операционной системы техническими специалистами Microsoft это слово было механически "переведено" как "персонализация", что попало в пользовательские интерфейсы операционной системы с настройками оформления окон и пр.; затем слово примелькалось в этом смысле и дошло до рекламщиков матрасов. Насколько в русском нужно слово с противоречивыми смыслами, покажет время.

Comment: Иногда мне кажется, что рекламу просто дословно переводят с английского.

Comment: Да, вчера вот посетил "Новую Голландию", там в историческом здании тюрьмы "Бутылка" мелкие ресторанчики и питейные заведения. Впервые увидел, как вместо русского "_разливное пиво_" переводят **beer on tap** буквально: "**пиво на кране**" - ну хоть бы предлогом по-русски "пиво" с "краном" связали (из крана)!